# Change type of exception while preserving the stack trace

Tags: c#, wcf, asp.net-web-api, exception, stack-trace

I have a WCF Service communicating with a WebApi.  When My WCF Throw a custom exception, like AutoMapperMappingException when it serializes the exception back to WebApi I get a ReadFault because WebApi does not have Automapper installed.

Now this is a problem generically and can happen with any third party library, so I do no want to have to install the Third party library on the WebApi.

Is there a way I can change the type of an exception while preserving the stacktrace.

I would like to do something like this (each exception would need it's own custom implementation but that's okay):

```
public void ThrowKnownException(AutoMapperMappingException ex)
{
    var message = FormatMessage(ex);

    var knownException = new Exception(message);
    knownExcpetion.StackTrace = ex.StackTrace;

    throw knownException;
}
```

This won't work because you can't assign a StackTrace.  Does anyone know of a clean way to do this?

**Edit:** 
Adding an inner exception to will not work,  because WCF still needs to serialize the inner exception to webapi which will create a read fault

Comment: Are you opposed to just adding it as an Inner Exception?

Comment: @Lithium yes,  Adding an inner exception Won't work because the inner exception also needs to be serialized back

Answer (score 0):

You can use overloaded constructor to wrapper your exception as InnerException

[Exception Overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/804f22sf(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: That won't work the inner exception is serialized as well, which will create a readfault

Comment: In my opinion you should never return exception stack in WCF response because of security concerns. In any production service it is not advisable to throw exception disclosing the stack.

Comment: agreed, we have a mechanism on our WebApi which filters the permission on what is seen by users from exceptions.   This can only be seen internally by certain users